# jquery calling another function

Tags: jquery, html, function, constructor

I am trying to call a function called `gallery_image_slider()` from within the `$(document).ready(function()` function.

Here is what I tried, but doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                gallery_image_slider();
            });

            function slider() {

                $('.projects_gallery ol').click(function() {
                    $("p.projects_gallery ol:first").addClass("intro");
                });

            function gallery_image_slider() {

                $('.project_desc_2').hide();
                 $('#project2').hide();
                 $('#description2').hide();

                 $('#project1').hover(function() {
                    $('#description1').show();
                   $('.project_desc_1').show();

                     $('.project_desc_2').hide();
                     $('#description2').hide();
                  });

                $('#project2').hover(function() {
                    $('#description2').show();
                 $('.project_desc_2').show();
                $('.project_desc_1').hide();
                        });


                $('#project1').mouseleave(function() {
                 $('.project_desc_2').hide();
                 $('#description2').hide();
                });     

                $('#project2').mouseleave(function() {
                 $('.project_desc_1').hide();
                 $('#description1').hide();
                }); 

            }
            }
```

How can I do this and also, how do I call multiple functions within another function?

Answer (score 2):

you just have syntax errors,  you can easily call multiple functions from document ready

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            gallery_image_slider();
            slider(); // <-- do this if you want to, calling multiple function is easy
        });

        function slider() {

            $('.projects_gallery ol').click(function() {
                $("p.projects_gallery ol:first").addClass("intro");
            });
        }  // you missed this

        function gallery_image_slider() {

            $('.project_desc_2').hide();
             $('#project2').hide();
             $('#description2').hide();

             $('#project1').hover(function() {
                $('#description1').show();
               $('.project_desc_1').show();

                 $('.project_desc_2').hide();
                 $('#description2').hide();
              });

            $('#project2').hover(function() {
                $('#description2').show();
             $('.project_desc_2').show();
            $('.project_desc_1').hide();
                    });


            $('#project1').mouseleave(function() {
             $('.project_desc_2').hide();
             $('#description2').hide();
            });     

            $('#project2').mouseleave(function() {
             $('.project_desc_1').hide();
             $('#description1').hide();
            }); 

        }
          // <-- removed extra curly bracket
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely missed it!